# Mysql Dump using R

Tags: r

I have a mysql database and I am using R to create a dump (actually database into .csv to be precise), I am using the following code:

```
require(RMySQL)
m<-MySQL()
summary(m)
con <- dbConnect(MySQL(), user="username", password="password", dbname="db", host="xxxxx", client.flag=CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS)

tables<-dbListTables(con)

for (i in 1 : length(tables)){
  temp <- (dbReadTable(con, tables[i]))
  temp <- temp[1:300,]
  write.csv(temp, tables[i], row.names=F)}
```

As you can see I just want the top 300 rows, the issue here is that the R is reading all the rows and only then doing a subset (slow) can you guys think of a better way to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    for (I in 1 :length(tables))
{
    temp1<-dbSendQuery(con,  paste("Select * from ", tables[I], " limit 300", sep=""))
    data1=fetch(temp1)
    write.csv(data1, tables[I], row.names=F)
}
```

Comment: The idea here is to NOT read all the data by using `dbReadTable`. Hope it is clear.

Comment: I just wanted to add this one information, in case of Mysql db the query will be: paste("Select * from ", tables[I], " limit 300", sep="")

Comment: Oh Ok. What version of MySQL are you running anyway?

Comment: Version of Mysql 5.1.73